# How to store list of JSON data in a Django model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

What is the best way to store a list of JSON dictionaries in a Django model field?

I am creating a transaction application for shops and I am trying to store the items of each order in a field **without relying on relational models**. Each item in this list will have a `name`, `quantity` and `unit_price`.

For example:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Product #1",
        "quantity": 1,
        "unit_price": 25.0
    },
    {
        "name": "Product #2",
        "quantity": 1,
        "unit_price": 50.0
    }
]
```

I am using a PostgreSQL database, but I've heard it's bad practice to use database-specific fields, such as `ArrayField`. What would be the best way to go about this and that would also keep the DRF serialization as simple as possible?

Comment: Why is it bad to use use database-specific fields?
never saw project change his db while he was in production.

Comment: Simple and best way to do this is relational models. This is the main deal about django models and databases. There is some reason to not use ?